# Nuxt environment variables exposed in client when uploaded to Zeit/Now

Tags: environment-variables, nuxt.js, dotenv, vercel

I am deploying a Nuxt App with Zeit/Now. In the development phase I was using a `.env` file to store the secrets to my Contentful CMS, exposing the secrets to `process.env` with the nuxt-dotenv package. To do that, at the top of the nuxt.config I was calling `require('dotenv').config()`.

I then stored the secrets with Zeit/Now and created a now.json to set them up for build and runtime like so:

```
{
    "env": {
        "DEMO_ID": "@demo_id"
    },
    "build": {
        "env": {
          "DEMO_ID": "@demo_id"
        }
    }
}
```

With that setup, the build was only working for the index page and all of the Javascript did not function. Only when I added the env-property to the `nuxt.config.js`file, the app started working properly on the Zeit-server.

```
require('dotenv').config()

export default {
...
env: {
   DEMO_ID: process.env.DEMO_ID
  },
...
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/dotenv'
  ],
...
}
```

BUT: When I then checked the uploaded Javascript files, my secrets were exposed, which I obviously don't want.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Same problem happens to us. One of the our app secrets was exposed. Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't necessarily doing anything wrong here, this is just how Nuxtjs works.

Variables declared in the `env` property are used to replace instances of `process.env.MY_ENV`, but because Nuxt is isomoorphic, this can be both on the server and **client**.

If you want these secrets accessible only on the server, then the easiest way to solve this is to use a [`serverMiddleware`](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-env#servermiddleware).

> As serverMiddleware is decoupled from the main Nuxt build, env variables defined in nuxt.config.js are not available there.

This means your normal ENV variables should be accessible, since the server middleware are run on Node.

Obviously, this means these secrets won't be available client side, but this works if you have something like a Stripe secret key that you need to make backend requests with.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem in our project. Even, We created a nuxt project from scratch and checked to see if there was a situation we skipped. We noticed that, while nuxt building, it copies the .env variables into the utils.js in the nuxt folder. Through the document [here](https://github.com/nuxt-community/dotenv-module), we changed the modules section in nuxt.config.js as follows,

```
modules: ['@ nuxtjs / apollo', '@ nuxtjs / axios', ['@ nuxtjs / dotenv', { only: ['']}]],
```

Then we noticed that .env variables are not exposed.

I hope it helped.

Our nuxt version is "nuxt": "^ 2.13.0".

Also, some discussion over [here](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/16).